# How to access docker container from different machine(Computer)?

Tags: docker, networking, porting, docker-container, docker-image

I have created docker image through mounting script file in container and then install necessary dependancies  in the running container and save the content of container by using commit command.

The main issue is that Multiple applications are up/running at multiple port inside the container .But before tackling that part I have Encountered very strange issue that I am running my docker image by using -p (Publish) command ,giving me satisfactory result in my host machine ,but I am not able to access the same port from different computer(By using IP of my machine) . I have tried almost all possible solution still not getting expected output?

I have run my docker image using by providing suitable port number through (-publish ) command .

```
docker run -it --hostname docker1 --name testrun12 -p 8079:8079  b6a555d1a373
```

Please Help me over this ,I have gone through many articles,implemented lots of part ,still result is the  same

Comment: Are you getting any specific errors when you try to connect (and if yes can you add those?)

Comment: Can you share the specific steps to recreate the image?  Preferably in the form of a Dockerfile?  "Multiple applications on multiple ports" isn't a standard Docker setup, and if you've set this up wrong some services you expect to be running might not be.

Comment: @ladygremlin I am not getting any specific error .Working well  for my localhost but when I tried to access running container from another machine ,browser giving me issue "Refused to connect"

Comment: @DavidMaze ,First of all I created docker image of base image of OS (Alphine in this case ) . Now,I have created my docker container  by mounting script file in that ... .and then install necessary dependancies from that script file and save the content of running container to new image by using commit command.
Thats how I have created my docker image

Answer (score 1):

By default Docker redirects all incoming traffic from all interfaces throught that port to the container, since you're not able to connect from others machines, i think that's a firewall issue.

Try to use common ports like 80 or 443, usualy firewalls allow all kind of traffic through those ports.

Answer (score 0):

You only published the ports from the container and so they'll be available on localhost. To be able to access the container from outside, you'd need to have the container access the host network too (unless you have more services running on the host and there may be conflicts).

Look into using `--network host` or for further reading peruse Docker's documentation on the networking - https://docs.docker.com/network/

Comment: `docker run -p` as shown should make the ports accessible from other hosts.  You specifically need to say `docker run -p 127.0.0.1:8079:8079` to make them _not_ accessible.